# Do helper functions in a NuGet Packages init.ps1 have to be global?

Tags: powershell, nuget, nuget-package

I'm wanting to write a couple commands for the [NuGet package manager](http://nuget.org) console to insert [Gists from GitHub](http://gist.github.com).  I have 4 basic commands

- **List-Gists** 'user'
- **Gist-Info** 'gistId'
- **Gist-Contents** 'gistId' 'fileName'
- **Gist-Insert** 'gistId' 'fileName'

All of my commands depend on a couple utility functions, and I'm struggling with whether they need to be global or not.

```
# Json Parser
function parseJson([string]$json, [bool]$throwError = $true) {    
    try {
        $result = $serializer.DeserializeObject( $json );    
        return $result;
    } catch {                
        if($throwError) { throw "ERROR: Parsing Error"}
        else { return $null }            
    }
}

function downloadString([string]$stringUrl) {
    try {        
        return $webClient.DownloadString($stringUrl)
    } catch {         
        throw "ERROR: Problem downloading from $stringUrl"
    }
}

function parseUrl([string]$url) {
    return parseJson(downloadString($url));
}
```

Can I just have these utility functions outside of my global functions, or will I need to include them in each of the global functions definition scope somehow?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No they don't. From your init.ps1 you can import a powershell module that you wrote (psm1) file and moving forward, this will be the way we recommend adding methods to the console environment.

Your init.ps1 would look something like this:

```
param($installPath, $toolsPath)
Import-Module (Join-Path $toolsPath MyModule.psm1)
```

In MyModule.psm1:

```
function MyPrivateFunction {
    "Hello World"
}

function Get-Value {
    MyPrivateFunction
}

# Export only the Get-Value method from this module so that's what gets added to the nuget console environment
Export-ModuleMember Get-Value
```

You can get more information on modules here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878340(v=VS.85).aspx

Comment: Good convention, but is there a way to access $toolsPath from the function defined within the module?